# How to get rid of the music player buttons when not playing music/podcast/etc?

Tags: zune-player

The music player buttons that pop-up (rewind, play/pause, fast-forward) when hitting the volume controls are nice, but when not playing music they get kind of annoying (taking up screen space).

Is there a way to manually remove them when not using them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now there is no built in solution without rebooting the phone. However, there are apps that do fill the gap. I use one called [Stop The Music](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/0899997d-c25a-4075-9b28-685308e1568b). All it does is clear the "now playing"playlist. It does so with no extra frills and can even pin a tile that stops the music, and then quits.

There likely are other options, but this is the one I use.