# How can I stop (not pause) music?

Tags: music

Whne I play music, the buttons are back/pause/next. When I press pause, it becomes a play button. If I pause music and go back to the main screen and do something else, when I come back into music later, the same song is paused.

Is there no way to press Stop and have my list of music to choose from, short of turning the phone off and on again?

Answer (score 3):

Short of using an app like [Kill My Music](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/kill-my-music/d69f3635-5bec-4ad4-8b43-240246cd0ede), no, there is no way to press Stop. Of course if you went back to any of the lists (albums, songs, playlists, etc.) you can restart from there.

Note apps like these also gets rid of the pop up music controls that appear when you hit the volume buttons.

Related: [How to get rid of the music player buttons when not playing music/podcast/etc?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/532/how-to-get-rid-of-the-music-player-buttons-when-not-playing-music-podcast-etc)